# name 'spark' is not defined in pyspark (Spark Version 1.6.3)

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As I am using `Spark Version 1.6.3` in `hdfs` in `pyspark` it give me an error:

```
df=spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",conn_url).option("drive","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("dbtable","W_DIM_TIME").option("user","mvr").option("password","****").load()
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please post the whole code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Spark 1.6 is no longer maintained. Can you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an undefined SparkSession instance, which isn't available until Spark 2.0.

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version

Otherwise, you must use a SQLContext - https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases